# Why doesn't this link?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker

I have pretty much the same issue as [unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184027/unresolved-external-symbol-public-thiscall), but since I've defined all my methods, the solution there doesn't apply here.

I have a Node.h with:

```
template<typename T>
class Node{
    public:
        Node(T data, Node* next);
}
```

In Node.cpp, I was sure to put:

```
#include "Node.h"

template<typename T>
Node<T>::Node(T data, Node* next){
    //I doubt that the implementation is relevant.
}
```

In both files, I `#include "stdafx.h"` to cater to visual studios.

Yet, when I try to instantiate a node with:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Node.h"

int main(){
    Node<int> n = Node<int>(9, nullptr);
    return 0;
}
```

I get:

```
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Node<int>::Node<int>(int,class Node<int> *)" (??0?$Node@H@@QAE@HPAV0@@Z) referenced in function _main
```

Just to debunk a few initial theories:

- I have put all the files in the same VC++ project.
- There are no methods declared in the header that are not defined (VC++ has ensured this).
- I instantiate the node in main.cpp, hence the uses of main.obj in the error.

Is there another issue that I don't see (maybe a Node.h crawling the standard library or some VC++ thing I'm missing). Comparing this to older code I have that does work, the only difference I can find is that the old code doesn't use generics. Are the generics the culprit?

Why won't these files link up correctly? How to avoid this in the future?

Comment: Pretty much the same problem - when the compiler sees just a declaration, it assumed *someone else*  has instantiated the template. Bu t *someone else* hasn't done that, so the linker can't find it.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry to post a duplicate, I just never considered that templates would be so fiendishly complex. I guess I don't know what I don't know.